# Depth First Search of Direct Graph (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, depth-first-search

[Direct Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgPGP.png)

I am struggling to do a depth first traversal on a direct graph that is an arraylist of linkedlists.

The correct traversal should be : 0 2 4 5 1 3
However, my traversal is : 0 2 4 5 1 as it stops there otherwise I am stuck in an infinite loop.

For context, the Vertex/Node is a string (even though it's an int for this example).

```
    ArrayList<LinkedList<Vertex>> graph;
    Vertex vertex;

    public DirectedGraph() {
        graph = new ArrayList<>();
        
    }

    public void dfSearch(Vertex vertex) {
        Stack<Vertex> stack = new Stack<>();
        String stringVal = null;
        int positionNum; // linkedlist position
        int graphCounter = 0; // arraylist position

        stack.push(vertex); 
        vertex.wasVisited = true;   

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex a = stack.pop();
            System.out.println(a.data);
                        
                        // iterates through linkedlist and pushes into stack
            positionNum = 1;
            while (positionNum < graph.get(graphCounter).size()) { 
                Vertex next = graph.get(graphCounter).get(positionNum);
                next.wasVisited = true;
                stack.push(next);
                positionNum = positionNum + 1;
            } 
                        
                       // retrieves and stores Vertex/Node data
            stringVal = graph.get(graphCounter).get(positionNum-1).data; 
    
            // search for stringVal data within arraylist(graph)
            int i = 0;
            String search = graph.get(i).get(0).data;
            while ( search  != stringVal)  {
                i = i + 1;              
                search = graph.get(i).get(0).data;
            }
                        // once stringVal is found, its linkedlist position is stored
            graphCounter = i;
        }
    }


    public void dfs(int start) {
        dfSearch(graph.get(0).get(0));
    }
```

Comment: How is `graph` defined?

Comment: Graph is defined as an arraylist that contains linkedlist. I updated my question to include the constructor if that is what you mean.

Comment: maybe better to include a [mre] in the question - otherwise we must guess what the missing code is doing or not doing

Comment: A good opportunity to learn about debugging  to see where exactly the execution of the algorithm differs from what you expect. (Can be done with a debugger or simply with print-statements and pen and paaper)

Answer (score 1):

The DFS algorithm goes like this:

```
        1 Start by putting one of the graph's vertices on top of a stack.
        2 Take the top vertex off the stack and add it to the visited list.
        3 Add adjacent vertices which aren't in the visited list to the top of the stack.
        4 Keep repeating steps 2 and 3 until the stack is empty.
```

Notice in particular step 3

Add adjacent vertices which ***aren't in the visited list*** to the top of the stack.

In your code you have

```
 next.wasVisited = true;
```

However, nowhere in your code do you check the value of wasVisited!!!